# Hard Drive POV clock

Tags: arduino

I am building a hard drive POV clock. (google it, they are pretty cool)
I am working on the code for it, right now all i want to do is get the hang of making it do simple patterns with the RGB leds. I am wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to do something simple like make a red line rotate around the platter.

right now what i have is an interrupt that triggers a function.

```
    int gLED = 8; // pins for RGB led strip
    int rLED = 9;
    int bLED = 10;

    attachInterrupt(0, ledPattern, FALLING);

    void ledPattern(){
        digitalWrite(gLED, HIGH);  // This will make a stable image of slice of the
        delayMicroseconds(500);    // platter, but it does not move.
        digitalWrite(gLED, LOW);
    }
```

That is the main part of the code (obviously I cut some stuff out that arduino requires)
What I am trying to figure out is how can make that slice rotate around the platter. 
Eventually I will make the pattern more interesting by adding in other colors.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Do you have a *specific* question?  Simply asking for ideas is not likely to get much of a response.  Also, is this C or C++?

Comment: It'll be neither standard C nor C++. The language for Arduino is essentially whatever AVR-g++ currently supports (http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_cplusplus)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a delay at the start of `ledPattern` before turning the LEDs on, and increasing that delay each time the interrupt is called. To display a line at a particular angle, you will need to measure the time between subsequent interrupts (the time taken for one whole revolution of the LEDs) and make all the delays in the `ledPattern` routine proportional to this time.

Be aware that, if too much delay is added, the `ledPattern` routine won't have returned by the time the next interrupt is called; you might need to mitigate this, or at least work out exactly what the arduino environment is doing in this situation.